# How to perform safe pattern matching on existential types in Scala 2.13?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-safety, existential-type, scala-2.13

**Note:** This is a contrived example.

Consider the following existential type.

```scala
sealed trait Showable

final case class Show[A](show: A => String, value: A) extends Showable
```

I can define a `show` method as follows:

```scala
def show(showable: Showable): String = showable match {
  case Show(show, value) => show(value)
}
```

But the pattern match infers the type `Any => String` and `Any` for `show` and `value` respectively. Hence, I can also define a `show` method as follows:

```scala
def show(showable: Showable): String = showable match {
  case Show(show, value) => show(42)
}
```

This is unsafe. How do I ensure that within the case expression `show` can only be applied to `value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you match a typed pattern then

```
def show(showable: Showable): String = showable match {
  case s: Show[a] => s.show(s.value)
}
```

or

```
def show(showable: Showable): String = showable match {
  case s: Show[_] => s.show(s.value)
}
```

compiles but

```
def show(showable: Showable): String = showable match {
  case s: Show[a] => s.show(42)
}
//type mismatch;
// found   : Int(42)
// required: a
```

or

```
def show(showable: Showable): String = showable match {
  case s: Show[_] => s.show(42)
}
//type mismatch;
// found   : Int(42)
// required: _
```

doesn't.

Comment: Brilliant. This works. But how does it work? Is `a` a (universally quantified) type variable? Is the type of `a` inferred?

Comment: @AaditMShah https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#typed-patterns *"A typed pattern `x:T` consists of a pattern variable `x` and a type pattern `T`. The type of `x` is the type pattern `T`, where each type variable and wildcard is replaced by a fresh, unknown type. This pattern matches any value matched by the type pattern `T`; it binds the variable name to that value."*

Answer (score 1):

You could use dependant types to make it typesafe

```
sealed trait Showable

sealed trait Show extends Showable {
  type Inner
  def value: Inner
  def show(a: Inner): String
}

object Show {
  type Aux[A] = Show {
    type Inner = A    
  }
  
  def apply[A](f: A => String, a: A): Aux[A] = new Show {
    type Inner = A
    def value: Inner = a
    def show(a: Inner) = f(a)
  }

  def unapply(show: Show): Option[(show.Inner => String, show.Inner)] = Option(a => show.show(a), show.value)
}



def show(showable: Showable): String = showable match {
  case Show(show, value) => show(value)
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify the definitions of `Showable` or `Show`. They're provided by an external library.